# remove pseudo css class dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, html, extjs, extjs4.2

I am using extjs 4.2.2.1144 in my project, which is generating one pseudo css class as below

// To remove outline from individual components that need it instead of resetting globally

```
.#{$prefix}webkit {
    * {
        &:focus {
            outline:none !important;
        }
    }
}
```

which is generating css as below:

```
.x-webkit *:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

This is causing performance issue in editable table in IE only but for chrome its working fine, if I remove this the performance is improving significantly.

Is there any way to unload(without removing from css file) this  pseudo class in page load using simple javascript or jquery?

Comment: I don't think we can achieve it using JS. CSS is the perfect way to do this. OR you can try with calling a blur()

Comment: @Ananya could you tell me how can I do it for onblur?

Comment: the problem is with :focus. If I remove :focus with :active or :hover then its working fine. So I want to unload the entire class.

Comment: entire class or just selector?

Comment: I want to remove focus from x-webkit *:focus

Comment: Is there any prob if you are simply removing the css?

Comment: Yes, I can not remove the entire css since it is being generated from saas, if I remove then while rebuilding the project it will replace with the old one.

Comment: we can remove it from SASS and run grunt to generate new CSS. I don't think that would be a prob.

Comment: The scss file is being generated from extjs and for ext js we are using sencha cmd. We can not override scss file.

Answer (score 1):

You could scope your css by applying a class at the component level using 
`cls` property and then let the framework and the browser do the work for you.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-cls

Here is an example using the example from the documentation page above:

### In your component file (/project_root/app/view/.../MyComponent.js)

```
// My Component
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
  title: 'Contact Info',
  width: 300,
  bodyPadding: 10,
  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
  items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'name',
    fieldLabel: 'Name',

    cls: 'no-outline-on-focus' // <-- this will be applied to the component container 

    allowBlank: false 
  }, {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'email',
    fieldLabel: 'Email Address',
    vtype: 'email'  format
  }]
```

});

### In your sass file (/project_root/sass/etc/all.scss)

```
// the parent component with extjs generated styles
.no-outline-on-focus {

  // everything within this block is scoped to the element above. 
  *:focus {
     outline: none !important;
   }
}
```

Just in case you do not have the CLI installed, here is a link:
https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/cmd-download/

It sounds like you may already have it or already have a project set up, but wanted to send the link just in case.

If you do not wish to download the CLI or do not want it, here is a link to generate your own CSS output using SASS:
http://sass-lang.com/install

Sencha provides a ton of sass variables linked in the documentation which make styling and themeing a bit easier. :)

Comment: Thanks @djmm. I am new to extjs could you tell me how to scope the css in  component level?

Comment: Not a problem at all, @arat. I added an example to the post. :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the style property to the empty string will remove that property if it does not reside in a stylesheet.

This might work

```
$(".x-webkit :focus").css("outline", "");
```

Comment: the problem is with :focus. If I remove :focus with :active or :hover then its working fine. So I want to unload the entire class.

Comment: @Arat Try below code.


`$("head").append('<style>.x-webkit *:focus {
  outline: initial;
}</style>');`

But I think best option is override SASS.